# How do I bundle zeromq with an electron app?

Tags: zeromq, electron

Introducing `zmq` into my Electron app has proved to be onerous:

```
01:33:03 {master %=} rgbkrk@puter ~/code/jupyter-sidecar$ electron .
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2v89Signature3NewEPNS_7IsolateENS_6HandleINS_16FunctionTemplateEEEiPS5_
  Referenced from: /Users/rgbkrk/code/jupyter-sidecar/node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2v89Signature3NewEPNS_7IsolateENS_6HandleINS_16FunctionTemplateEEEiPS5_
  Referenced from: /Users/rgbkrk/code/jupyter-sidecar/node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

/usr/local/bin/electron: line 2: 46288 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron" "$@"
```

How should I be bundling zmq? All I did to get it setup as part of the environment is running `npm install --save zmq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [zeromq.js](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js).

It has the same API as `zmq` but features prebuilt static binaries for Node and Electron. So there is no need for a proper C/C++ compiler toolchain:

```
npm install zeromq
```

For Electron specific instructions checkout https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js#rebuilding-for-electron.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to copy libzmq.dylib into the same directory as the zmq.node folder